# Unterschied : Buße/Geldstrafe/Geldbuße

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen drei Wörtern: **Buße**, **Geldstrafe** und **Geldbuße**, die in meine Sprache anscheinend gleich übersetzt werden?

Comment: *Buße* can mean [repentance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance_(Christianity)) (and *Busse* can be the plural of [Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus)).

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage: I guess the problem here is that the questioner has no ß on it's keyboard = needs to copy or change keyboard settings. and I assume no hugh vehicles are meant due to "translate the same".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I guessed so, too. I thought it was still worth mentioning. If used in another context (e. g. without Geldstrafe or Geldbusse) it might lead to confusion ("Die Höhe der Busse ist unterschiedlich."). A trick I use to incorporate *Sonderzeichen* missing from my keyboard is looking it up, e. g. on wikipedia, and then copy paste the letter.

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher, die du zweifellos zuvor konsultiert hast? - Beachte aber jedenfalls, dass der Unterschied zwischen "Buße" und "Strafe" nicht rein semantisch verstanden werden kann. Vielmehr erschließt sich der Unterschied erst mit Bezug aufs jeweilige Rechtssystem.

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage Thanks, I updated with ß.

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage *Busse* can also be Schwyzerdytsch spelling of *Buße*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je nach Kontext werden die Wörter synonym verwendet oder unterschieden. Ausführlicher die Erklärung zu der Verwendung von Geldbuße und Geldstrafe als staatliche Maßnahme.

In Deutschlands Justizsystem unterscheidet das Wort den Grad des Vergehens & den Einbezug von Amtspersonen:

- eine Geldbuße wird von der Behörde für ein "einfaches Vergehen" verhängt.
- eine Geldstrafe wird von einem Gericht für eine Straftat verhängt.

D.h., eine Geldbuße wäre ein per Behördenmitarbeiter verteilter Strafzettel wegen Falschparken. Eine Geldstrafe wäre "x Tagessätze à 100 Euro" für eine gerichtlich festgestellte Straftat.

[Wikipedia zur Geldbuße](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geldbu%C3%9Fe_(Verwaltungsrecht)):

> Unter Geldbuße (auch: Bußgeld) versteht man im Verwaltungsrecht eine Geldzahlung, die bei geringfügiger Verletzung der Rechtsnormen wegen Ordnungswidrigkeit durch Behörden verhängt wird. Im Strafrecht gibt es die vom Gericht verhängte Geldstrafe

[Wikipedia zur Geldstrafe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geldstrafe_(Deutschland)):

> Die Geldstrafe ist im Strafrecht eine Strafe, die nur durch ein Urteil oder durch einen Strafbefehl im Strafprozess verhängt werden kann[...]

Strafen sind auferlegte Sanktionen gemäß eines Regelwerkes - eingangs genutzt das [StGB](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgesetzbuch), andere sind z.B. in individuellen Verträgen festgehalten (=> Vertragsstrafe). Im Deutschen Justizsystem soll mit dem gerichtlichen Verhängen der Strafe [das Ziel erreicht werden](https://www.bpb.de/izpb/268220/vom-sinn-und-zweck-des-strafens?p=all), `"die Gesellschaft vor sozialschädlichem Verhalten zu bewahren und die elementaren Werte des Gemeinschaftslebens zu schützen"`. Der eigentliche Zweck ist weniger klar und Gegenstand der Diskussion (`"Schuldausgleich, Prävention, Resozialisierung des Täters, Sühne und Vergeltung"`). Ein betroffener Mensch als Opfer kommt quasi nicht vor. Zukünftige Auswirkungen der Strafe sollen beim Verhängen berücksichtigt werden ([§46(1) StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__46.html)): `"[...]  Die Wirkungen, die von der Strafe für das künftige Leben des Täters in der Gesellschaft zu erwarten sind, sind zu berücksichtigen"`

Bußen sind ähnlich der Strafe eine auferlegte Sanktion für ein definiertes Fehlverhalten, jedoch darauf ausgelegt, dass der/die Sünder/in durch das büßen (=Buße durchführen) sein Verhalten für die Zukunft ändert. Neben der eingangs erwähnten Geldbuße als Maßnahme einer deutschen Behörde (= im Staatskontext wie das StGB) gibt es Bußen häufig in Glaubensgemeinschaften. Der Zweck ist hier damit klarer umrissen als bei einer staatlichen Strafe. Im Christentum hat sich der Sünder idR gegen Gott versündigt, d.h. auch hier spielt ein Mensch als betroffenes Opfer quasi keine Rolle.

So gibt es "[Buße tun](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bu%C3%9Fe_(Religion))" im Christentum mit dem Ziel, dass man bereut und es [öffentlich zeigte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchenbu%C3%9Fe) bzw. (danach) schlicht sein Leben anders = "christlich" führt, sonst muss man wiederum Buße tun (je nach Konfession).

Comment: In deinem Link steht nichts davon, dass das öffentliche Zurschaustellen von Reue ein Teil der Buße wäre.

Comment: @sgf: für mich ist "öffentliches zeigen" damit gegeben, dass ich etwas nicht im Verborgenen tue. Damit: ja, die Vergangenheitsform wäre "passender" (->Kirchenbuße), jedoch ist es beim C-Zweig Katholiken noch üblich, etwas zu tun ("das Erfüllen eines Werkes der Wiedergutmachung, das in Gebet, Almosen, Dienst am Nächsten, oder freiwilligem Verzicht bestehen kann").

Comment: Buße ist nicht die Aussage, dass ein Verhalten sanktioniert wird, sondern die Sanktion selbst. Eine Strafe kann, folgt man Deinen Ausführungen, nicht von einem Lehrer oder den Eltern oder sonst wem verhängt werden? Auch ein Verein kann die Spieler nicht mit Geldstrafen belegen, etwa wenn sie nach 23:00 Uhr vor einem Spiel noch in der Disco gesichtet werden? Was ist mit Vertragsstrafen unter Geschäftspartnern - gibt es die auch nicht?

Comment: @userunknown: stimmt, Flüchtigkeitsfehler. Zumindest hatte der/ die Frager offenbar den staatlichen Aspekt im Blick. Ansonsten danke für die Hinweise, habe "ausgebaut".

Answer (score 1):

*Buße* bedeutet einerseits *Sühne* oder *Reue* (vgl. Büßer), andererseits aber auch eine Bestrafung für eine Rechtsverletzung.

*Geldstrafe* und *Geldbuße* sind weitgehend Synonyme und bezeichnen einen Geldbetrag, der für eine Rechtsverletzung zu bezahlen ist. Welcher Begriff zu verwenden ist, hängt - wie in der Antwort von Shegit Brahm erläutert - von der Art Rechtsverletzung und auch der Höhe des zu entrichtenden Geldbetrags ab.

Comment: Einwand: juristisch sind Buße und Strafe sehr unterschiedlich.

Comment: Ja, ich habe das noch ergänzt. Laut dwds.de sind beide Begriffe jedoch synonym.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar  Da gibt das dwds dann aber wirklich eine sehr verkürzte (um nicht zu sagen: verstümmelte) Antwort. In jeglicher zeitgenössischen Alltagsverwendung von *Buße* und *Strafe* ist der Einfluss der juristischen Begriffsverwendung präsent. Anders mag das vielleicht noch in der Kirche sein. Aber wer geht noch in die Kirche...

Comment: @ShegitBrahm abgesehen vom Formalismus ist der Effekt für den Bürger weitgehend gleich. Dass beides unterschiedliche Namen tragen muss ist keinesfalls ofensichtlich. So findet sich Strafe etwa auch in *Vertragsstrafe*.

Comment: Inwiefern hängt der richtige Begriff von der Höhe des Betrags ab?

Comment: @vectory Der Effekt für den Bürger ist keineswegs gleich. Eine Geld*strafe* wird im Strafregister eingetragen, der Missetäter ist somit vorbestraft. Eine Geldbuße hingegen führt nicht zu einem Eintrag, der Täter ist als *nicht* vorbestraft, was beim polizeilichen Führungszeugnis oder bei Bewerbung um ein öffentliches Amt einen *gewaltigen* Unterschied bedeutet!

Comment: Deshalb kann es in Fällen, bei denen bei einem Prozess um eine minderschwere Straftat eine Verurteilung absehbar ist, und das Gericht, um den formalen Aufwand abzukürzen, dem Angeklagten die Einstellung des Verfahrens gegen Zahlung einer Geldbuße anbietet, sogar vorkommen, dass die Höhe dieser Geldbuße *über* der Höhe der zu erwartenden Geldstrafe im Verurteilungsfall liegt.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf der Effektivwert einer Wechselspannung ist equivalent dem einer bestimmten Gleichspannung, trotzdem sind die lebensbedrohlichen Grenzwerte unterschiedlich. So geht ein Busgeld wegen Verkehrsvergehen meist ebenso mit einem Eintrag in einem Register einher, das ggf. auch den Job kosten kann, wenn genügend Einträge zusammen kommen. Desweiteren darf bezweifelt werden, ob jeder Verkehrssünder reuig ob der Buße wird, jedenfalls vor dem Führerscheinentzug, der dann allerdings ganz richtig als *Strafe* durch Urteil ergeht.

Comment: @vectory Vielleicht hätte ich ausdrücklich darauf hinweisen sollen - auch wenn Strafzettel wegen Verkehrsdelikten die zahlenmäßig häufigste Erscheinungsform von Bußgeldern sind, hatte ich diese nicht gemeint, sondern Fälle von strafrechtlichen Prozessen, in denen eine Einstellung gegen Zahlung eines Bußgeldes angeboten wird. Meine juristischen Kenntnisse reichen nicht aus, um sicher zu sagen, welche Voraussetzungen dazu erforderlich sind, aber es dürfte bei Wirtschaftsvergehen und bei minderschweren Fällen von (Beamten-)Beleidigung (oder sogar Eigentumsdelikten?) möglich sein.

Answer (score 0):

Der Unterschied zwischen Buße und Geldbuße ist trivial: Eine Buße muss nicht in Geld geleistet werden - im Jugendstrafrecht kommen etwa auch Arbeitsstunden in gemeinnützigen Einrichtungen in Betracht, im religiösen Kontext Gebete, die man sprechen muss (2 Rosenkränze und 10 Vaterunser).

Beim Buße tun unterstellt man eher innere Anteilnahme und empfundene Reue, beim Bußgeldzahlen für 's Falschparken aber wiederum nicht.

Den Unterschied im juristischen Sprachgebrauch hat Shegit Brahm gut herausgearbeitet; allerdings gibt es Geldbußen und Geldstrafen auch in Rechtsgeschäften zwischen Vertragspartnern und im laienhaften Sprechen, welches nicht selten ist, wird die Unterscheidung oft nicht so scharf getroffen.

Im religiösen Kontext ist Buße dominant.

Answer (score -1):

Buße und Strafe haben große Bedeutung in der Theologie. Eventuell stammen die Begriffe sogar daher. Eine genaue Etymologie ist mir nicht bekannt (*Strophe, Leitsatz, Schuldspruch*?).

Der entscheidende Unterschied dürfte meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach sein, dass Buße eine "Wiedergutmachung" bedeutet, während eine Strafe für unverzeihliche Taten, quasi nur zur "Abschreckung" vor der Nachahmung gedacht ist.

Soweit im Sprachgebrauch von *Strafe verbüßen* die Rede ist, besteht wohl kein scharfer Kontrast im Volksmund.

Während *er ihn straft*, aber *er etwas büßt*, wird ebenso deutlich: Buße erfordert Aktivität, aber Strafe wird passiv, bzw. antagonistisch erfahren.

Wie @Geiselmann schon sagte, ist es halt vom Kontext abhängig. Die liturgische Deutung des Themenbereichs ist dabei oft ziemlich pathetisch. Die Deutung der Bundesrichter des letzten Jahrhunderts dagegen ist "grausam"--Wortlaut Prof. Pauen (HU Berlin), selbst etwas sarkastisch, doch wunderbar doppeldeutig.

Comment: Was genau soll "(Strophe, Leitsatz, Schuldspruch)" bedeuten? Und worauf bezieht sich "Die Deutung der Bundesrichter [...] wunderbar doppeldeutig."? Sind diese beiden Textstellen für eine klare Antwort überhaupt relevant? Ich habe den Eindruck, man könnte beides streichen, aber vielleicht übersehe ich was.

Comment: @Arsak die bezeichneten Urteile und Kommentare der Bundesrichter, die sich spätestens nach Neuordnung der deutschen Verfassung (viz. Grundgesetz) auf rechtsphilosophischer Ebene mit dem Für und Wider des Bestrafens auseinander setzen mussten, habe ich leider nie gelesen. Ich finde lediglich die Bezeichnung "grausam" bemerkenswert ironisch, da vom Prof. einerseits *grauenhaft schlecht* gemeint gewesen scheint, andererseits *notwendiger weise absichtlich schrecklich* im Sinne *furchteinflößend* unterschwellig mitklingt.

Comment: Zu *Strophe* will ich mir eine kurze Randnotiz nicht nehmen lassen. *Strophe* (auch *Vers*, En. "stanza") soll verwand sein mit *Katastrophe*, *Unglück*, *unglückliche Wendung*, auch AGr. *katastrepho*, "to subjugate", AGr. *kata-*, "downwards". Vgl. daher Ger. **ab-strafen**. AGr. *stroph-*, wird übrigens als "to turn" erklärt .... "Strophe" selbst passt aber eben auch zu *Satz, Spruch*. Der Ansatz bedürfte der Ausarbeitung. *Tenor* (Mittelalter Latein?) passt via *tense* aber auch zu dem bekannten Ansatz bei bspw. Pfeiffer, der *straff* nennt. Das würde wiederum zu *Zusammenfassung* passen.

Comment: Da "to turn" sehr vielseitig ist und unzählige Synonyme, Meto- und Meronyme hat, ließen sich jede Menge Metaphern vermuten, etwa *bindendes Urteil* (s. a. *binden*, "fesseln"), oder *Entschluss* (falls *schließen* enger mit Drehbewegungen zusammenhängt; Vgl auch *Schlüssel* für *Code*, *Passphrase*--Das ist ein Thema für sich). Das würde hier viel zu weit führen.

Comment: Eine Proto Indo Europäische Wurzel im Zusammenhang mit Strafe wird auch mit "payment" gedeutet (bspw bei Ivanov und Gramkrelidze, hab ich aber grad nicht parat, PIE \*k^w-???) Dieser Laut wurde in einigen Sprachen zu *P*, vgl. *pay*. Vgl. etwa analog "Tages-Satz"; Auch Analog, aber wohl nicht direkt mit Strafe verbunden wäre *to tell* vs *Zahl*. Das einzige was mir zu *B* ~ *P* einfällt, um *Buße* dazu zu stellen, ist leider nur Monty Python's "Pöser Pursche" in Das Leben des Brian. Zwar wird \*g^w- auch zu *B*, aber deshalb gleich *Geld*, *ab-gelten* zu sehen birgte mehr Fragen als Antworten.